# NSOperationQueue, concurrent operation and thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I'm developing a sort of fast image scan application.
In the `-captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:` method I pick up the CVPixelBuffer and add them into an `NSOperation` subclass. The `NSOperation` takes the buffer and transform it into an image saved on the filesystem.
The `-isConcurrent` method of `NSOperation` returns YES. After the operation is created, is added to an `NSOperationQueue`.
Everything runs fine except for one issue that is affecting the scan frame rate.
Using time profiler I've found that some of the NSOperation are run on the same thread of the AVCaputureVideoOutput delegate that I've created:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("it.CloudInTouchLabs.avsession", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
[dataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:(id)self queue:queue];
```

When an operation is running on the same thread of the AV session queue, it affects the frame rate, it happens only with some them, probably GCD is deciding under the hood dispatching on active threads.
 The only method I've found to solve that issue, is to create a separate thread and pass it to the the single operations forcing them to run on it.
 
Is there another way, to force operations run on a different thread?

**[EDIT]**
Following the @impcc suggestions I made some test.
Results are pretty interesting even if sort of inconsistent.
Test platform is an iPhone 5 connected in debugging mode through an MBP with 16gb of RAM quad core i7. The session has a 60fps output tested with the algorithm in RosyWriter apple sample code. 
**AVSession queue sync targeted to high priority queue**

- 26 fps where sometimes the thread of the queue is shared with the one
  of the operation. The time taken inside the delegate methods has an
  average of 0.02s
- 14 fps with a thread created just for the operations, if the main
  method is not called on this thread, the start will be forced to perform
  on that specific thread. This thread is create one time and kept
  alive with a dummy port.. The time taken inside the delegate is
  0.008.

**AVSession queue concurrent targeted to high priority queue**

- 13.5 fps  where sometimes the thread of the queue is shared with the one of the operation. The time taken inside the delegate methods has
  an average of 0.02s, substacially equal to the counterpart with sync
  queue.
- 14 fps with a thread created just for the operations, if the main
  method is not called on this thread, the start will be forced to perform
  on that specific thread. This thread is create one time and kept
  alive with a dummy port. The time taken inside the delegate is
  0.008.

**Conclusion** 
Concurrent or serial queue doesn't seems to make a big difference, however concurrent for me is not ok cause of the timestamps that I need to take to preserve the sequence of single picture. The fact that is surprising me is the frame drop using an ad-hoc thread, even if the time taken inside the delegate method is considerably less, the frame rate drops about 10fps. Just trusting in GCD the frame rate is better but the delegate methods takes more than 2 times to finish, this probably due to the fact that sometimes the AV queue is used by also the nsoperations. 
I can't really get why the time taken inside the delegate doesn't seems to be correlated to the fps. Shouldn't be the faster the better?
By further investigations it really seems that what is stealing time si in the process of adding and probably executing operation in queue.

Comment: Threads and queues should not be looked at as the same thing. In theory, GCD is supposed to create as many threads as possible for optimal performance.

Comment: Thanks, I know. Just wondering if exist a way to avoid the use of the same thread used by a specific queue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you might be misunderstanding the meaning of `isConcurrent`. This is totally understandable, since it's incredibly poorly named. When you return `YES` from `-isConcurrent` what it really means is "I will handle any concurrency needs associated with this operation, and will otherwise behave asynchronously." In this situation, `NSOperationQueue` is free to call `-start` on your operation synchronously on the thread from which you add the operation. The `NSOperationQueue` is expecting that, because you've declared that you will manage your own concurrency, that your `-start` method will simply kick off an asynchronous process and return right away. I suspect this is the source of your problem.

If you implemented your operation by overriding `-main` then you almost certainly want to be returning `NO` from `isConcurrent`. To make matters more complicated, the behaviors associated with `isConcurrent` have changed over the years (but all that is covered in the official docs.) A *fantastic* explanation of how to properly implement a returns-`YES`-from-`isConcurrent` `NSOperation` can be found [here.](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/05/05/concurrent_operations/)

The way I'm reading your question here, it doesn't sound like your `NSOperation` subclass actually needs to "manage its own concurrency", but rather that you simply want it to execute asynchronously, "on a background thread", potentially "concurrently" with other operations.

In terms of assuring the best performance for your `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` callbacks, I would suggest making the queue you pass in to `-setSampleBufferDelegate:queue:` be (itself) concurrent and that it target the high-priority global concurrent queue, like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("it.CloudInTouchLabs.avsession", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
dispatch_set_target_queue(queue, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0));

[dataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:(id)self queue:queue];
```

Then you should make the delegate callback methods as lightweight as possible -- nothing more than packaging up the information you need to make the `NSOperation` and add it to the `NSOperationQueue`.

This should ensure that the callbacks always take precedence over the `NSOperations`. (It's my understanding that `NSOperationQueue` targets either the main queue (for the `NSOperationQueue` that's associated with the main thread and run loop) or the default priority background queue.) This should allow your callbacks to fully keep up with the frame rate.

Another important thing to take away here (that another commenter was getting at) is that if you're doing all your concurrency using GCD, then there is only *one* special thread -- the main thread.  Other than that, threads are just a generic resource that GCD can (and will) use interchangeably with one another. The fact that a thread with a thread ID of X was used at one point to service your delegate callback, and at another point was used to do your processing is not, in and of itself, indicative of a problem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Very thorough and knowledgeable. If someone told me there were an iOS Bible and you were the co-author, I would believe it. Happy holidays.

Comment: That's a great explanation. You've got everything about my problem. I will try as soon as possible and post result later. About creating a concurrent AVSession queue I'm afraid it will mess up my code, because the delegate callback isn't "much" thread safe and I take timestamps, to rebuild later the sequence (with msec precision), but I will try because I'm really curious to explore and understand if I get some concepts about GCD.

Comment: A serial queue will probably be fine. The most important thing is to make your callback methods simple and fast, offloading any significant work to other contexts.